# How to have an integer variable update as a result of a ChangeListener added to a JSlider

Tags: java, swing, event-listener, jslider, changelistener

Im having a bit of bother with a JSlider at the moment, Im fairly new to java so this may be easily rectified.

I have a JSlider that looks like this here: 
[JSlider Gui Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g27LE.png)

What I want to be able to do is have the "0" constantly update to the value of the JSlider. I have a ChangeListener added with .getValue() called upon the JSlider and set equal to an int variable as seen in this image: [JSlider Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPQIu.png)

This int variable has been declared in the class so its not local to any methods, the System.out.println() proves that the ChangeListener is working as the value of the JSlider is constantly updated and printed in the console however the int variable does not seem to hold its value outside of this ChangeListener and therefore will not display the current value in the border where I want it to.

Does anyone have any clue on how to resolve this?

All Relevant code is here:

```
JPanel sectorSlider = new JPanel();

sectorSlider.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
TitledBorder sectorSliderBorder;

final int sectorNumberMin = 0;
final int sectorNumberMax = 50;
final int sectorNumberInitial = 12;
        JSlider sectorNumberSlider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL,
        sectorNumberMin, sectorNumberMax, sectorNumberInitial);
       sectorNumberSlider.setMajorTickSpacing(10);
sectorNumberSlider.setMinorTickSpacing(5);
sectorNumberSlider.setPaintTicks(true);
sectorNumberSlider.setPaintLabels(true);

sectorNumberSlider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent event) {
        sectorValue = sectorNumberSlider.getValue();
        System.out.println(sectorValue);
    }
});

sectorSliderBorder = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(blackline, "Number of Sectors: " +sectorValue);

sectorSliderBorder.setTitleJustification(TitledBorder.CENTER);
sectorSlider.setBorder(sectorSliderBorder);
sectorSlider.add(sectorNumberSlider);
```

Comment: Copy and paste!

Comment: Please share some (more) code that isn't an image.

Comment: Please don't make more work for people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), for SE to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: `.setTitle() method however it is still not updating when the ChangeListener is working.` - Did you display the value returned from the slider? if you have a reference the Border and the listener is invoked and the value is correct then the Border should update correctly. If not, then you still have a problem with your code.  Post your proper [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> will not display the current value in the border where I want it to.

That is because you have not changed a property of the Border.

All you have done is change the value of the variable. That variable is in no way associated with the Border. You just used the value of the variable to initially set the title of the Border when you created the Border.

The code in the `ChangeListener` should be:

```
sectorSliderBorder.setTitle( ... );
```